# Making button siblings wrap like words

Tags: html, css

I need to make every syllable of certain phrase a button. Is it possible to make it behave like regular text when it comes to wrapping?

Here's what I mean, in the first image every syllable is just plain text, in the second one it's `<span>` and in the third, it's `<button>`:

[image: Wrapping]

```css
body {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
}

div {
    background-color: #444;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 180px;
}

div,
button {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: orange;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Hippopotamus amphibius
</div>
<div>
    <span>Hip</span><span>po</span><span>pot</span><span>a</span><span>mus</span> <span>am</span><span>phi</span><span>bius</span>
</div>
<div>
    <button>Hip</button><button>po</button><button>pot</button><button>a</button><button>mus</button> <button>am</button><button>phi</button><button>bius</button>
</div>
```

I'd like the `<button>` version to behave like the first two. I know I could wrap unbreakable parts together in containers, but I have a lot of text and I'd prefer it to wrap like that without altering the text structure.

Is it possible with CSS?

Comment: what about placing all the button for the same word inside a span with display:inline-block?

Comment: That's what I mentioned in the post, I'd like to avoid having to separate words, because it's not a static text.

Comment: @TemaniAfif also I'm pretty sure the algorithm of word wrapping is not as trivial as it seems. There are certain characters that can or cannot trigger the wrapping.

Comment: buttons behave like inline-block elements so each button is now a word and the algorithm that apply on the first two examples is no more relevant. For this reason an extra wrapper is the simplest solution

Comment: Ah simple 'word-wrap' in CSS would do the trick. But you don't have a button, you have 8. How are we supposed to know where the word ends or begins?

Comment: @Wimanicesir I'm missing your point. I said I want to make buttons behave like `<span>`, for example.

Comment: can you use a span and add a click handler on it? you dont technically need to use a button element. although you lose semantics and accessibility features

Comment: (Keyboard) accessibility might be easier to achieve, if you used `<a href="#">` instead of spans. (Otherwise, adding at least `tabindex="0"` might be a good idea.) As for semantics - not sure how much there is to "lose" here in the first place, how much semantics can "words randomly hacked apart into multiple buttons" have had to begin with.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad yeah, I will do that as a last resort if I don't find a CSS-way to make buttons behave like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use display contents to get the correct wrapping.

> *'display: contents'* causes an element's children to appear as if they
> were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element
> itself. This can be useful when a wrapper element should be ignored
> when using CSS grid or similar layout techniques.

```css
body {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
}

div {
    background-color: #444;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 180px;
}

div,
button {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: orange;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Hippopotamus amphibius
</div>
<div>
    <span>Hip</span><span>po</span><span>pot</span><span>a</span><span>mus</span> <span>am</span><span>phi</span><span>bius</span>
</div>
<div>
    <button>Hip</button><button>po</button><button>pot</button><button>a</button><button>mus</button> <button>am</button><button>phi</button><button>bius</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about `display: contents`. It's said that most browsers can't handle the accessibility of the buttons with `display: contents` applied, so it might be the same as using spans with click handlers, but I will do a further research. Thanks!